# ALM server unreachable error while execution in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, hp-uft, alm

I am running UFT automation test from ALM through Jenkins. I have created a job and associated Alm server details. when executoing the job i am getting the following error

Started by user anonymous

Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QTP_JOB2\workspace
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QTP_JOB2\workspace\HpToolsLauncher.exe" -paramfile props05012016175826489.txt

"Started..."

Timeout is set to: 10000

Run mode is set to: RUN_LOCAL

Invalid server response
Error: "ALM server unreachable, check that server Url is correct"
Build step 'Execute HP functional tests from HP ALM' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your alm server url may be wrong configured.
[You can check the url here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq0hZ.png) in jenkins' configure. Make sure the url is visitable.

The field could validate the url after version 4.0.1. You can use the Latest Release to avoid wrong configured again. [You can get it here.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HP+Application+Automation+Tools)